# Can you help identify this bike?

Tags: mountain-bike, full-suspension, identify-this-bike

[image]

I have been given this bike and am trying to find out more about it - I can't find anything on the bike that tells me it's make etc - any ideas would be very welcome.

Comment: which country are you in? does it look like its been repainted? do you see a serial number (normally found under the bottom bracket)?

Comment: The lack of labelling on almost all the components leads and the general shape of the frame leads me to think it's a generic deparment store bike.

Comment: Can you add some close-ups of anything and everything that has a name or logo on it? I see something on the seatpost, front shock, and maybe the rear shock. If there are any other labels that we can't see in this pic, those would help too.

Comment: @Kibbee - or stolen.

Comment: I'm in England I was given the bike by my wife's friend who's owned it for a while so not stolen @Daniel R Hicks. It has been repainted not by me but before I received it I believe it is part carbon fibre the serial number is A70800024 on the frame. It has club roost bars and I think its a specialised crank and drive train. Thanks for everyone's comments so far.

Comment: The problem is that many bikes look alike, even though the construction may be radically different.  With old style steel bikes the bike may be made of high-quality Reynolds tubing or no-name stuff little better than cast iron --  you can't tell, short of weighing the bike.  With newer bikes it may be hacked-together welded aluminum or good-quality carbon -- again, hard to tell.  Without decals or at least identifiable components the most you can do is guess at the overall quality.

Answer (score 4):

I see...

A Marzocchi Bomber fork, construction and decals look like a [late-90s Bomber Z1](http://www.retrobike.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?t=198026), though slightly different from the pictured "bam" model.

An FSA headset.

A [ROOX seatpost](http://www.roox.at/COMPONENTS/COMPONENTS/Seatpost_overview.htm), though I didn't try to find the exact model from as little as visible.

A Cane Creek rear shock.

Cheap department store bike was my first guess, but the identified parts seem a bit better than that for as little as I pay attention to who is selling their brand to junk bike makers.

Comment: Also the brake levers and cantilevers look like Shimano LX brakes from the late 90ies to me. Not the worst stuff back then and quite sure not from a department store bike.

Comment: It could be an old Yeti. http://www.bikepedia.com/QuickBike/BikeSpecs.aspx?year=1999&brand=Yeti&model=AS-3+Comp+L%2fXT The dept store bikes are essentially cheap copies of that design.

Comment: Trek Y is also similar to that design.

Comment: The forming and clean welds on the frame suggest that it is more than just a cheapo Dept store suspension bike. At one time ( mid 90s or so ) that design was state of the art, rather than a mark of shame.

Comment: It has been repainted not by me but before I received it I believe it is part carbon fibre the serial number is A70800024 on the frame. It has club roost bars and I think its a specialised crank and drive train mark you are correct with the other parts you mentioned in your post.Thanks for everyone's comments so far.